# After Ajax Request Select Option not Resetting

Tags: jquery

I have a form in which there is a title, select option, and content. What I am doing is I am taking all the data and sending it to the server via ajax, I am able to reset the input fields but I am not able to reset the select option box.

following is my select box code:

```
<select name="post_category" class="post_category round select2 form-control" id="id_h5_single">
    <option selected disabled value="">Select Post Category</option>
    <option value="Am">America</option>
    <option value="Nt">Netherland</option>
</select>
```

Following is the jQuery code that I am using to reset the above field:

```
// $('.post_category').prop('selectedIndex',-1);
// $('.post_category').val($(this).find('option:first').val());
// $("select.post_category option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled');
// $("select").val("");
$('.post_category').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

The commented code is the codes I've used it. What I want to do is, when the page loads by default it shows in select `Select Post Category`. I want to display the same after the ajax request when I reset it. However, I am finding difficulties in it. What's wrong I am not able to get it.

Comment: try `$('.post_category option[value=""]').prop('selected',true);`

Comment: Can't select a disabled option. Get rid of `disabled`. Can simplify also by just setting value of select ... `$('.post_category').val('')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you an example that approach your goal. When document loads, after `1 second` the select is changed to `America`, and `4 seconds` later will be changed again to the default value.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".select2").select2();
    
    setTimeout(
        function(){$("#id_h5_single").val("Am").change();},
        1000
    );
    
    setTimeout(
        function(){$("#id_h5_single").val("").change();},
       5000
    );
});
```

```css
.select2{
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select name="post_category" class="post_category round select2 form-control" id="id_h5_single">
    <option selected disabled value="">Select Post Category</option>
    <option value="Am">America</option>
    <option value="Nt">Netherland</option>
</select>
```

But, since you are using the **select2 plugin**, the best approach for what you want is to use the placeholder, not a default disabled option. You can check this on next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".select2").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Post Category",
        allowClear: true
    });
    
    setTimeout(
        function(){$("#id_h5_single").val("Am").change();},
        1000
    );
    
    setTimeout(
        function(){$("#id_h5_single").val("").change();},
       5000
    );
});
```

```css
.select2{
  width: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select name="post_category" class="post_category round select2 form-control" id="id_h5_single">
    <option value="Am">America</option>
    <option value="Nt">Netherland</option>
</select>
```

Comment: hi @D. Smania,  understood the logic you explained and then i modified my code a bit so this one worked perfectly as i wanted `$(".post_category").val("").change();`